# How do I access class properties using 'self = this'?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm having trouble accessing a class property from within a method. My code is roughly as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    self: MyClass = this;
    someString: string = "Hello world!";

    myMethod() {
        return self.someString;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error: `Property 'someString' does not exist on type 'Window'.` I don't understand how `self` can be of type `Window`; after all I explicitely declared it as type `MyClass`, and this does not give me any errors.

I am aware I could just use `return this.someString` in this case, but this code sample is just a simple demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Have you ever done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `self` in your example

```
class MyClass {
    someString: string = "Hello world!";

    myMethod() {
        return this.someString;
    }
}
```

Use `this` to access inner fields

If you want to try to access with `self` you also should use `this`:

```
myMethod() {
    return this.self.someString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it is unnecessary to create a self-property on class-level, cause you would have to access it as `this.self.whatever` and it will only be an alias for `this.whatever`. Your complicating things, without any benefit.

self makes only sense to keep a reference to `this` inside of a closure, 
without using `.call(this)` all over the place

```
class Foo {
    data: any[];  //let's assume `data` is populated
    bar(){
        var self = this;
        this.data.forEach(function(v, i){
            //`this` points to the global namespace
            //you have to reference it through `self`
            console.log(i, v, self);
        })

        //or you use lambdas
        this.data.forEach((v,i)=>{
            //then TS takes care of `this`
            //lamdas don't have an own `this`- or `arguments`-object
            //ES6 treats them the same way.
            console.log(v,i,this);
        });
    }
}
```

OT, just for completenes:
`forEach()` has a second argument to pass the `this`-object so you could actually write

```
this.data.forEach(function(v, i){
    console.log(i, v, this);  
}, this);
```

but this isn't the actual topic of this question

Answer (score 2):

Your code is transpiled into something like following (see the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground)).

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.self = this;
        this.someString = "Hello world!";
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
        return self.someString;
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
```

You aren’t creating the self in the object’s scope. The `self` you are referring in the `myMethod` is actually a [`Window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/self).

To make the error obvious, try renaming `self` to something else:

```
class MyClass {
    moo: MyClass = this;
    someString: string = "Hello world!";

    myMethod() {
        return moo.someString;
    }
}
```

This now results into correct error `Cannot find name 'moo'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.moo'?`

If you want to access your `self` property, you have to use `this.self`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code can be used:-

```
    "use strict"
class myClass {


    constructor(someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
        self = this;
    }




    myMethod() {

            return this.someString;
    }
}

 var p1 = new myClass("Hello World");


console.log(p1.myMethod());
```